# ASP:NET : My Dive can't set full screen(of monitor) from inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an iframe in my web site , and the iframe loads site pages .
One of my page is include a button, after users click on this button , a full screen div should display. I want make a div to fit my full screen browser, but it just full screen in iframe.
For example:
WebForm11.aspx

```
 <iframe src="WebForm12.aspx" width="200px" height="200px"></iframe>
```

WebForm12.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#show').click(function () {
         $('#d1').show();
     })
 });
 </script>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show-hide" />

<div id="d1" style="background-color:Red;display:none;"></div>
```

How can i display this red div in monitor full screen ?

Comment: Move it to parent window.

Comment: tnx for answer, but i dont understand. can you explain it to me?

Comment: I mean that you need to move the div that you try to make it full screen to the parent window, the one that handle the iframe, ether by always have the div there, ether create it with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move it to parent window and it become true.( as in the comment said)